# How to get the URL of a page where a Google Script Gadget is embedded

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a method that allows me to get the URL of the current page where a Google Script Gadget is embedded.

I tried using getActivePage() but that only returns my Google Site's home page.  According to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=568 get active site and get active page is defective but that was in September 2011...

Here is my code:

```
    var site = SitesApp.getActivePage();
```

Am I using getActivePage() incorrectly?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit 1 attempt:

```
  var templates = site.getTemplates();
  var template;
  var names = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    if (templates[i].getName() == 'profile') {
      template = templates[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (template != null) {
    var pageName = name;
    Logger.log('Found: ' + pageName);
    site.createPageFromTemplate(pageName, pageName, template);
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Not Found');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following script

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var lbl = app.createTextArea();
  lbl.setWidth('100%');
  lbl.setHeight('100%');
  var txt = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl();
  lbl.setText(txt);
  app.add(lbl);
  return app;
}
```

and a couple of pages embedding the Google Script Gadget linked with this script. The script's output is the same as the URL in the internet browser address bar.

@LehanCoetzee code.

```
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('profile').evaluate();
    site.createPageFromTemplate(name + ' ' + surname, name, templ);
```

'profile' is an html template I created through the apps script editor.

**Edit 01:**
I created a template page with a Gadget linked to my script above. The script's name is `ProfileTemplate`. Also I created a new page with the following script.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var tb = app.createTextBox().setName('tb').setId('tb');
  var btn = app.createButton().setText('Create').setId('btn');
  var out = app.createTextArea().setId('out');
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('onBtnClick');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  btn.addClickHandler(handler);
  panel.add(tb);
  panel.add(btn);
  panel.add(out);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}

function onBtnClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var site = SitesApp.getActiveSite();
  var out = app.getElementById('out');
  var templates = site.getTemplates();
  var template;
  var names = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
    if (templates[i].getName() == 'profiletemplate') {
      template = templates[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  if (template != null) {
    var pageName = e.parameter.tb;
    out.setText('Found: ' + pageName);
    site.createPageFromTemplate(pageName, pageName, template);
  }
  else {
    out.setText('Not Found');
  }
  return app;
}
```

If to open the new page, to type a text, for instance, test1 or test2, and click the `Create` button, then a new page from the template will be created. The templated page will have have an URL similar to https://sites.google.com/a/..../.../test1 for the text "test1" and the Gadget's output will contain this text.

Comment: Thanks.  I also did a test where I created a new page and then inserted the gadget, which then returned the correct URL.  It still however doesn't work in the following context:  I have a script that creates a new page by getting the html content of another page which is populated with two gadgets and some html.  It seems that after creating that page through the script the gadget for some reason then outputs the URL as the sites homepage and not the actual page it's on.

Comment: @LehanCoetzee: I did not dig so deep but how about to use the Site class [createPageFromTemplate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_site#createPageFromTemplate) function instead of a page HTML content copying.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly could you maybe check if my code is correct?  I'll paste it underneath my original question.

Comment: @LehanCoetzee: See the Edit 01. So, the SitesApp.getActivePage() function works correctly.

Comment: I tried using your code but I can't get it to work.  site.getTemplates() doesn't seem to be executing.  I think it might be because 'site' is declared with SitesApp.getSiteByUrl(), where you used getActiveSite().  My code is executing from a form submit trigger and the form isn't embedded on a page so I can't getActiveSite.  Thanks again for your help, I apologize for all the trouble.

Comment: @LehanCoetzee: Just tested my site using the `SitesApp.getSiteByUrl()`. It works. The problem is not in this line but somewhere else. In any case I gave an answer to your question. If you would like to proceed, please make a new question. Otherwise we confuse the others. Please provide a minimum sample of your not working code, which is possible to reproduce, in a similar way as I did. It will be easier to help you. BTW have you created a template from your page as I wrote?